# Card payment in PayPal from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, paypal

I am using Excel and vba to work.
Using https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment I am trying to send a transaction for testing. But I get a 401 error.
I get accessToken earlier.
I think the error may be related to the JSON generation. But maybe I'm wrong ...

I ask you to point me to an error

```
        Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    tempStr = "{" & JParam("intent", "sale") & "," & _
        Chr(34) & "payer" & Chr(34) & ": {" & _
            JParam("payment_method", "paypal") & "," & _
            Chr(34) & "payer_info" & Chr(34) & ": {" & _
                Chr(34) & "shipping_address" & Chr(34) & ": {" & _
                    JParam("line1", myAddress1) & "," & _
                    JParam("line2", myAddress1) & "," & _
                    JParam("city", myCity) & "," & _
                    JParam("state", myState) & "," & _
                    JParam("postal_code", myZipCode) & _
                "}}," & _
        Chr(34) & "funding_instruments" & Chr(34) & ": [{" & _
        Chr(34) & "credit_card" & Chr(34) & ": {" & _
            JParam("number", myCreditCardNumber) & "," & _
            JParam("type", myNameOnCard) & "," & _
            JParam("expire_month", CStr(myExpirationMonth)) & "," & _
            JParam("expire_year", CStr(myExpirationYear)) & "," & _
            JParam("cvv2", myCVV) & "}}]}," & _
        Chr(34) & "transactions" & Chr(34) & ": [{" & _
        Chr(34) & "amount" & Chr(34) & ": {" & _
            JParam("currency", "USD") & "," & _
            JParam("total", CStr(myTotalOrderAmount)) & "}}]}"
    
    
    
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/payment", False

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken

    xmlhttp.send tempStr
    
    If xmlhttp.status = 200 Then
    
        MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
    Else
        MsgBox "Error! " & xmlhttp.status
    End If
    
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing

Private Function JParam(parameterName As String, parameterValue As String) As String
    JParam = Chr(34) & parameterName & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & parameterValue & Chr(34)
End Function
```

JSON result:

```
{
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
        "shipping_address": {
        "line1": "52 N Main St",
        "line2": "52 N Main St",
        "city": "Johnstown",
        "state": "OH",
        "postal_code": "43210"
        }
    },
    "funding_instruments": [{
        "credit_card": {
            "number": "4417119669820331",
            "type": "visa",
            "expire_month": "11",
            "expire_year": "2022",
            "cvv2": "874"
        }
    }]
},
"transactions": [{
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "234.45"
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: I have fixed the errors in the code (thank you Tim), but the 404 error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Access token should be sent like this:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & accessToken
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But now I am getting error 400.

Comment: That's "bad request" so likely there's some problem with the JSON you're sending in the request body.  Have you tried `Debug.Print tempStr` to make sure it looks as you expect?

Comment: The problem is I am not sure if the JSON is correct. Help PayPal is very large, and I can not find 100% of a suitable example for me. So I have collected JSON from various sources.

Comment: FYI you're using a deprecated API (v1) and the replacement v2 API does not include a `payment` action.  See the note here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that in the current version of the API it is impossible to create a payment by card?

Comment: I'm just pointing out what it notes on the linked page - I'm not at all familiar with PayPal processes...